# How to Use Touch Gestures for Keyboard Devices - Autohotkey Script?

Tags: scripting, touch, autohotkey, gesture

**How can i Use Touch Gestures for Keyboard Devices - Autohotkey Script?**

I want to Work Smarter on My Standard Keyboard Device, with **INTELLIGENCE GESTURES KEYS MOVEMENTS**

So that i do not need to move Both Hands to my Keyboard Device. (with this methodic i can Stay Always With my Hand on the Mouse Device)

On Touchscreens you have Gestures Tools, where you can do Multi Finger Taps to execute any Kind of Computer movements (Keyboard Shortcuts Macros), **Why not do this on Keyboard Devices.**

The AHK Script must can do this:

1 - [Click c] = Send c

2 - [Click 5x c] = Execute Script Part 5

3 - [Right Click v] + [Left Tap c] = send ^c ;Ctrl+c

4 - [Left Click c] + [Right Tap v] = send ^v ;Ctrl+v

5 - [Right Hold v] + [Left Tap c] = Execute Script Part 1

7 - [Left Hold c] + [Right Tap v] = Execute Script Part 2

8 - [Click c + v together (at the same time)] = Execute Script Part 3

9 - [Click x + c + v together (at the same time)] = Execute Script Part 4

[image: touch gestures for keyboard]

[image: gestures left tap] [image: gestures right tap]

My Ahk Script for Multi Clicks is:

Example1.ahk

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force
;#NoTrayIcon

a1 := -1
b1 := 0

esc::exitapp ;You can click the (esc) key to stop the script. 

;Use character ($) if you want to send hotkey itself ($c::send c)
;Click 5x C Key on keyboard, to Execute Ahk Code Part 5
$c::
if(a1 = -1)
{
a1 := 4
#Persistent
SetTimer, CountClicks, 100
}
else
{
a1 := 3
}
return

CountClicks:
if(a1 = 3)
{
b1 := b1 + 1
}
if(a1 = 0)
{
msgbox you did Click <C> Key > %b1%x times
if (b1=1) 
{
;if Click 1x - Then Execute Ahk Code Part 1 
;Here you can put any code for Part 1
;send c     
} 
if (b1=2) 
{
;if Click 2x - Then Execute Ahk Code Part 2  
;Here you can put any code for Part 2       
} 
if (b1=3) 
{
;if Click 3x - Then Execute Ahk Code Part 3 
;Here you can put any code for Part 3  
Send {Volume_Mute} ;Send, Volume_Mute     
} 
if (b1=4) 
{
;if Click 4x - Then Execute Ahk Code Part 4 
;Here you can put any code for Part 4       
} 
if (b1=5) 
{
;if Click 5x - Then Execute Ahk Code Part 5 
;Here you can put any code for Part 5       
} 
b1 := 0
SetTimer, CountClicks , off
reload ; restart script
}
a1 := a1 - 1
return
```